# redirect to mobile website using PHP

Tags: php, html, redirect, mobile

I have use [this](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/) to generate this code:

```
<?php
    require_once('mobile_device_detect.php');
    mobile_device_detect(true,false,true,true, true,true,true,'http://m.mydomain.com',false);
?>
```

But the only directions are to "copy and paste this code". Um.. copy and paste where? Do I need to create a new php file? Is this `index.php`? What if I already have an `index.html` file?

EDIT: I understand that I put `mobile_device_detect.php` in the root of `mydomain.com`. My question is where to put the above php code.

Comment: Support for the script you're using: https://andymoore.desk.com/customer/portal/topics/217720-detect-mobile-browsers/articles

Comment: @Aknosis I've seen that. They don't say where to put the code.

Comment: @soleil no offence but you need to learn little basics.

Comment: @soleil no need to be sarcastic. I was sincere with that comment. The thing is, you need to look at the file to see how it detects the browser. Create a bool (true or false) fuction depending on the existing detection. then use an `if-else` condition to redirect to different locations depending on the device. had i had the file, i could have tell but no way i am paying or going through spreading words for a file like that.... (the function looks so ugly to be honest).

Answer (score 5):

Copy and paste this at the beginning of your PHP based pages that you want to detect the visitors for their device. If your server parses HTML files as PHP which I doubt then add this in your HTML files as well. If you're just building the website then yes you need this in files which are parsed by the PHP engine for example: ".php".
If you paste this in page that is HTML and not parsed by the server you'll see this same code as output which will do nothing. In order to have it working you need it in PHP files.
If your script is well written and well structured you may need to include it in only one place. It all depends how your website is structured.

------ UPDATE ------

Why you shouldn't be using this class? It have a special license which is not absolutely free. 
Instead you can use this simple class: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

1. Download **Mobile_Detect.php**
2. Include the file at the top in your PHP page where you want the device to be checked:

   ```
   // Include the mobile device detect class
   include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
   // Init the class
   $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
   // And here is the magic - checking if the user comes with a mobile device
   if ($detect->isMobile()) {
       // Detects any mobile device.
       // Redirecting
       header("Location: http://your_redirected_url.com"); exit;
   }
   ```
3. Creating rewrite rules for using html extension.
   If you still want to use '.html' as extension just create rewrite rule that will rewrite your .php as .html. Or otherwise said create your_page_name.php and add the PHP code there. Create .htaccess file in the same DIR and add the following lines:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^your_page_name.html/?$ your_page_name.php [L]
   ```

Save, close! Now you should be able to use your php page with .html extension. To access your page now just type: http://yourdomain.com/your_page_name.html
Simple as that!
*Suggestion:* If I was you I'd add the rewrite rules in the web server's config file. It will be faster and more secure. But that's another lesson. If you decide to use this method just search the Stack.

Comment: So you're saying I need to create an index.php page with just the code above in it? If the user isn't on a mobile device I obviously want them to see the normal index.html page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the code anywhere you want.  Just make sure the function is defined on any page that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

You should either buy the script `mobile_device_detect.php` from the site or use a free method called pay with a tweet option.. Go to the download page and you will see them there..

Comment: I have the script. The question is where to put the php code that calls the script.

Comment: You should put it on every page you want to redirect to the mobile version.. and remember the path to the script should be right. that is the important thing..

Answer (score 0):

ok, in case this helps someone, here are the details of what's working for me:

Create an index.php file with just this:

```
<?php

require_once('mobile_device_detect.php');
$mobile = mobile_device_detect();

// redirect all mobiles to mobile site and all other browsers to desktop site
if($mobile==true){
  header('Location:http://m.yourdomain.com/');
}else{
  header('Location:http://yourdomain.com/index.html');
}
exit;

?>
```

Drop the mobile_device_detect.php file in the root of your site.

Then, add this line to your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```