# How to redirect www.example.com/blog/ to www.blog.example.com?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to know how to redirect users to www.blog.example.com using htaccess or php. For example. I have a blog which is not wordpress. when users want to access blog, I want the url to read www.blog.example.com. The current url shows www.example.com/blog/

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect to mobile website using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534342/redirect-to-mobile-website-using-php)

Comment: check this [MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the following and I find it better than using some other code/library and you might want to visit the site once in a while to see if the code has changed.

taken from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

```
$useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i', $useragent)
|| preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent, 0, 4))){
    header('Location: http://m.mysite.com');
}
```

Also

Android tablets, iPads, Kindle Fires and PlayBooks are not detected by design. To add support for tablets, add `|android|ipad|playbook|silk` to the first regex.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to detect if they're on a mobile browser ([this might be a good start](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)) and then, you'll need to redirect. For that you can use the `header()` function to set location to the mobile version of your site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_match` to determine if the user-agent is a mobile one, then `header` to redirect to the wanted site

example:

```
if(preg_match('`(Android|Phone|Mobile|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|RIM)`i', 
   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ){
   header('location: http://m.yoursite.com');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You identify a device by looking at the user agent. [Here's a list of mobile user-agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/) that you can match against. If the user agent is one of those, then you know it's a mobile user and redirect them to `m.mysite.com`.